# Should I turn off my leaking hot water tank in winter?

Tags: leak, hot-water

Just noticed that the upstairs hot water tank is firing, and there is a bunch of water on the basement floor. (This is a duplex, and no one is living upstairs right now.)

So my first thought was just to turn off the burner and shut off the water going to it... but it's winter (albeit pretty warm today) so then I was afraid the pipes would freeze or something.

So what's the safer option here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I got no answer on this I'll post what the plumber said:

You only need to worry about the pipes freezing if the temperatures are going to be below 0 degrees fahrenheit. So it's ok to turn off the gas and water as long as it won't be that cold.